# Running a application made for Ubuntu 12, 14 or Windows on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: driver, windows, ubuntu, compatibility

I need to install an [ebeam edge](http://www.e-beam.com/es/soporte/generalidades.html) which need driver. It only works on Windows / Ubuntu. How do I know if I can make it run on Ubuntu Mate or Windows IOT on my Raspberry Pi? Do you think it is possible?

Comment: I don't suppose you've got the Bluetooth version?

Comment: Is the source code available ? I guess not. There is no chance this software runs on the Pi at all. Linux != x86_64 , my friends.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, you can't install this application to run on a Raspberry Pi, regardless of which OS you decide to put on it.

As far as I can tell from their website, their applications require an `x86` processor to run. Unfortunately, for your project, all current models of the RPi have an `ARM` processor. They're fundamentally different, and are not compatible.

We have a [blog post](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/140986024839/installing-applications-on-a-raspberry-pi-running) that gives a fairly broad explanation of the idea.